# Transparent PHP script execution using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a solution for this a problem: I need that every HTTP request (method is irrelevant) in Apache http server would be served only after execution of specific PHP script. This is needed because I need to gather some information about requests, etc.
As far as I understand - this could be achieved using `mod_rewrite` module. So far I have done this (in `.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.php [C]
```

`script.php` is executed, but I need that after this original request would be executed.

Thanks - any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wrong implementation can't have good solution Do you know about include() or require() in PHP?

Comment: I really can't see a point in this question. Can you add more info? Why this script needs to run before the original request? Can't this be solved using includes, requires or ob_start?

Comment: I need to get information (IP, method, etc) about request and then let it execute. As far as I know - inculde/require is not good, because it will not handle, for example, 'domain.com/file.txt?param=1'.

Comment: Oh God when I read this I understand why Internet is such a mess `(>_<)"`

Comment: Why not build this into your application put the php function into a header of all your files and before each file is loaded it will get the referring IP and path and execute your script as needed before loading the page.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

make script.php run your code and afterwards redirects using the filename variable you passed to it. ($_GET['filename'])

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar setup in the past in my 404.php page. I look at the url coming in, and if it matches something I'd expect I would use a LOCATION: header to redirect.

The purpose for this in my case was after a rewrite to the site, magazines, etc. that had linked to either deprecated sections or articles would just die at the 404. I wanted to take them to the correct content or at least a "friendlier" section.

Another use for it was to shorten urls so we could send out

www.oursite.com/special

Which didn't exist, so it would die to the 404. My switch/case looked for "special" and could redirect to...

www.oursite.com/some/place/inside/the/site/for/special/

Don't know if that helps... but it's one way to "pre-filter" and redirect traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with PHP anyway, why not use the `auto-prepend-file` (see [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)) settings. To add it conditionally via .htaccess see this [suggestion](http://www.codingforums.com/showpost.php?s=8f914b60d09c0091bb8a6e72296b56d9&p=389707&postcount=2).

Alternatively, it should be possible to use Apache RewriteRules to call your script via `RewriteMap`'s possibility to call external scripts.  (I do not think it is a good idea to do and would not recommend it)